# IN (?,?) Prepared statements mysqli precise values

Tags: ajax, mysqli, prepared-statement

Prepared statements are tricky for me with IN () clauses. I have a statement for an Ajax call that $_POST's an array of values.

I have a string of three values "1, 2, 3" which I explode to make a count for the bind clause (?) and bind string (s or i).

I am struggling to get the bind_params correct. The query does not work when the values are passed as a string in one go. eg:

```
$values = "1, 2, 3";
$bindString = "sss";
$stmt->bind_param($bindString, $values);
```

It does work when passed as individual values eg:

```
$value1 = "1"; 
$value2 = "2"; 
$value3 = "3"; 

$stmt->bind_param($bindString, $value1, $value2, $value3 );
```

Looking at a var_dump() I can see the value type is shown when each of the values are entered as a individual variable. But I am not sure if this is the reason or not for why I cannot get a string to work passed through one variable. I find this really hard to understand the correct format that is required.

As this query is dynamic and will have a lot of different values I need this to work well and safely prepared. So I need the best way to prepare the values passed from the AJAX post to deliver them to the prepared statement.

I have gone through other posts to try to find the way of preparing statements with IN (), and I have nearly got it, but much difficulty I think is based around the delivery of these values.

If someone can help me understand this correct delivery of values, I would be in a much better place I think: I hope this will be the final hurdle to getting this working. I have a few other queries with "IN ()" that need preparing. I hope I may not waste another day trying to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

note: just to clarify, I think the preparations for the bind string and clause is ok.

```
$bindClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count( $values ), '?'));

$bindString = str_repeat('s', count( $values  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherently use IN with mysqli prepared statements.  The easiest workaround that I have found to this is to use sprintf to create a string of question marks that you insert into your query string before you bind the variables to it.  Here is the way to get a string of the right number of question marks from your array of variables:

```
implode(",", array_fill(0, count(array(1, 2, 3)), "?"))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. Yes, this is something that is okay for me so far. I am using:     $bindClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count( $category_ids ), '?'));

$bindString = str_repeat('s', count( $category_ids  ));  to prepare these, it is the values entered that seem to be my problem.

Comment: Oh, I see.  This is what I always use: https://github.com/kloddant/db.  For binding the parameters, I use call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_map("sql::convert_to_reference", $parameters));.  It calls bind_param on $stmt using an array of the parameters as references.  Apparently the parameters that you pass to bind_param cannot be values; they have to be references.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if that is what you were asking either.  If you were asking if you could pass a string to bind_param instead of a bunch of separate variables, I think the answer is no, you have to pass the separate variables, but you can pass a dynamic number of them by using that call_user_func_array technique I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in the question. The problem for me is that I could pass value "1, 2, 3" in an unprepared statement IN ($values)  in one variable, but somehow I cannot do this in a prepared statement. I am sure it can be done, but somehow I am not giving the values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Although not answered, @kloddart has pointed me towards using a library. Not the one recommended, https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql was the one I have used. It is very clean and the instructions for use are clear. I have got close after research from a number of post to understanding how to do this manually but I need to get on with things right now. Maybe PDO needs to be considered, but I am now moving forward again with my project.